# High temperature of components to joining & soldering

Tags: power-electronics, soldering, electrical, electronic-load, soldering-iron-station

Please help me to know the best components for the process of welding an electronic circuit to operate it in a very high temperature environment up to more than 600 degrees Celsius?
Note: I do not know if I can use the Ultrasonic welding in my application, and add on it another component to soldering with tolerate the temperature for example 500 ? Is this possible?

Comment: Other than welding, which doesn't "use components", I don't know what you're asking about.

Comment: Is this possible questions are hard to answer, please be detailed and specific, you'll get better answers. The answer is yes, will it work for your application, we don't know what that is

Comment: Jony, what's the nature and purpose of the circuit?

Answer (score 1):

Very few, if any, conventional components can withstand 600°C. If you have a datasheet of such a component it will probably offer application information.

For thermocouples we just weld the junction using inert gas (TIG). 600°C is above the range for reliable long-term use of unprotected metals such as iron and copper in an ordinary atmosphere, you need metals that form a highly protective oxide such as Alumel or tungsten. Above 1000°C, noble metals come into play.